# Effects of setting PersistMessages to N and FileStorePath issues in QuickFixJ:

Tags: quickfixj

I am running into out of memory issues after a certain amount of time when I run my quickfixj app. After a little investigation I found out that this was being caused by messages that quickfixj caches for re sending when a resend request is received.

So for testing I set this flag to N on a particular session. After that my memory problems completely disappeared. But I do not understand why quickfixj is keeping these message in memory when I have properly set this property : FileStorePath. These messages should be stored into a file but they are not. I do see some files present in the directory I set in FileStorePath but none of them seems to be storing messages, I can only see sequence number in them. Do I need to set other flags besides this in order to make this work?

I do not plan to use PersisMessages flag outside testing. I would prefer FileStoreMaxCachedMsgs flag with a reasonable figure. I also need to know what will happen if my app receives a resend request when I have set PersisMessages to N? Will quickfixj send gapfills instead or will it crash with some exception message?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i ve found that quickfixj sends gap fills when it could not find messages. also the config flag FileStoreMaxCachedMsgs is used to tell quickfixj about how much messages it should keep in cache before pushing them down to files. so this flag, in my opinion, should be altered in order to get your app to work without running out of memory due to message caching.

hope it ll be helpful for somebody. Thanks